# What does $P(\overline{A}B)$ mean when $A$ and $B$ are two events?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

It is my belief that $P(\overline{A}B)$ means the $P(\overline{A} \cap B)$. However, I am not sure. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with your thought process. In the probability courses I've taken, it was standard practice to read something like $P(AB)$ as $P(A\cap B)$. In your scenario, $P(\overline{A}B):=P(\overline{A}\cap B)$ makes sense. However, I think we can take this one step further. Think of this in terms of a Venn diagram. We know that $P(\overline{A})$ represents the complement of $P(A)$, i.e., everything "not in" $P(A)$. When we take the probability of this intersected with the probability of $B$, we see the resulting area will be $P(B)$ without $P(AB)$.

Comment: The last part of your post seems to suggest that $P(\overline{A}B)$ means $P(B)$. Is that what you meant? If so it does not seem right to me.

Comment: Hey, Bob. I can see the confusion. What I'm trying to convey is the area representing $P(B)$ without the intersected middle portion. I'm not sure how to type it in LaTeX. Visually, this shaded region of a Venn diagram should look like whichever circle represents event $B$ with the overlapping portion for the intersection is removed.